# Cannot access WCF service on Remote server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, remote-server

I hosted WCF web service C# in a remote Windows VPS running with the basicHttpBinding.

The problem is that I Browse to the service URL on the server machine through remote desktop works fine, but trying to browse using the external IP address (either remotely or EVEN locally) does not work. (it displays to me the browser message "This site can’t be reached") Example:

http://localhost:99/Service1.svc (OK)

http://8.35.36.82:99/Service1.svc from remote desktop of server (OK)

http://8.35.36.82:99/Service1.svc from my machine (Not OK)

I already opened inbound port in server firewall

any ideas??

Web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>

<services>
  <service name="WebService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="http://8.35.36.82:99/WebService/Service1.svc" binding="BasicHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"  />
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: "Does not work" — best error description by far.

Comment: it displays to me the browser message "This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply put this in your configuration-->

```
<services>
  <service name="WebService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="BasicHttpBinding" contract="WebService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't help, nothing changed :(

Comment: What happens when you navigate to that url in a client app?

Comment: same status, I made the address  = "" and locally on remote server it runs good either http://8.35.36.82:99/Service1.svc or http://localhost:99/Service1.svc, but from my machine, doesn't http://8.35.36.82:99/Service1.svc

Comment: What error do you get when you put http://8.35.36.82:99/WebService/Service1.svc in your browser on your local machine? Also try http and https.

Comment: same message "This site can’t be reached 8.35.36.82 took too long to respond." ..  I tried http and https .. and same result , I even turned off the firewall on server .. nothing works :(

Comment: Next, I would check the IIS log, if that is what you are using and see if your request made it to the server and after that look into the windows application log on that server for errors when you try and connect.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <standardEndpoints>
      <webScriptEndpoint>
          <standardEndpoint name="webScriptEndpoint0" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webScriptEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
   <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBinding0">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBinding0">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="debugServiceBehavior" name="Backend.CoreService">
      <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpRest" binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding0" name="Unsecure.Backend.CoreService"  contract="Backend.ICoreService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpRest">
        <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"  faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="debugServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding0" scheme="http" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```